# Как очистить буфер ввода C++?

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой недописанный код. После ввода количества member enter остается во входной очереди и не получается ввести name класса string с помощью getline. Как избавиться правильно от этого перехода к новой строке и ввести имя и фамилию. Можно не только избавиться от него, но может написать код как то по другому. Массивы не хочу использовать, хочу поработать с классом string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct man
{
    string name;
    double sum;
};

int main()
{
    int member;
    cout << "Enter the number of members: ";
    cin >> member;
    cin.clear();
    man* ps = new man[member];
    for (int i = 0; i < member; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the first and last name of the member#" << i + 1;
        getline(cin,ps[i].name);
        cout << "Enter donation amount#" << i + 1;
        cin >> ps[i].sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался. Этот enter можно отбросить введя просто `cin.get().`

Comment: Это не в общем, а глубоко в частности.

Comment: @Harry да согласен. Но тут я писал в общем,что касается  моего кода

Comment: Не **КОДА**, а **ВВОДА**.